# How to apply a function to one part while keeping the rest?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list and want to apply a function just on the second `Part` and keep the rest.

```
t1 = Table[{k, 2^k + 1}, {k, 2, 7}]
```

yielding

```
{{2, 5}, {3, 9}, {4, 17}, {5, 33}, {6, 65}, {7, 129}}
```

I want to `FactorInteger` the second part to get

```
 {{2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3, 43}}}
```

By **not** using `Cases` like

```
 Cases[t1, {a_, b_} :> {a, FactorInteger[b][[All, 1]]}]
```

but by applying a function (maybe `Hold` or `HoldPattern`) which leaves `k` untouched when applying `FactorInteger` on the whole of `t1`. (I hope it makes sense what I am looking for.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
MapAt[Map[First] @* FactorInteger, {All, 2}] @ t1
```

> ```
> {{2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3,  43}}}
> ```

```
SubsetMap[#[[All,All,1]]& @* FactorInteger, {All, 2}] @ t1
```

> ```
> {{2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3,  43}}}
> ```

```
{#, FactorInteger[#2][[All, 1]]} & @@@ t1
```

> ```
> {{2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3,  43}}}
> ```

```
Module[{t = #}, 
   t[[All, 2]] = FactorInteger[t[[All, 2]]][[All, All, 1]]; t] & @ t1
```

> ```
> {{2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3, 43}}}
> ```

Comment: What does `@*` do? I can't find this in the docs.

Comment: @1110101001, see [Composition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)

Answer (score 8):

```
MapAt[FactorInteger[#][[;; , 1]] &, t1, {All, 2}]
```

Answer (score 8):

Rule approach starts with

```
rule1 = {x_,y_} :> {x, First /@ FactorInteger[y]};
```

and then

```
Replace[z1,rule1,{1}]
```

gives

> ```
>     {{2,{5}},{3,{3}},{4,{17}},{5,{3,11}},{6,{5,13}},{7,{3,43}}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
t1//Transpose[{#[[All,1]],FactorInteger[#[[All,2]]][[All,All,1]]}]&
```

> {{2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3, 43}}}

As `Inner` may be thought of as a generalized form of `dot`, a function may also be applied only to the `y` values as follows:

```
Inner[Times,t1,{1,1},{#1,FactorInteger[#2][[All,1]]}&]
```

> {2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3, 43}}}

---

**Fun with Inner/Dot**

```
ll={{a,b},{c,d}}
```

To multiply all `y` values by 10:

```
ll.{{1,0},{0,10}}
Inner[#1 #2&, ll, {1,1},{#1,10 #2}&]

(*
  {{a, 10 b}, {c, 10 d}}
  {{a, 10 b}, {c, 10 d}} 
*)
```

Or:

```
ll.{{1,0},{0,10}}==
Inner[#1 #2&, ll, {1,1},{#1,10 #2}&]==
Inner[Times, ll, {1,1},{#1,10 #2}&]==
Inner[Times, ll, {{1,0},{0,10}}]
```

> True

To apply a function only to the `y` values of `ll`:

```
Inner[Times,ll,{1,1},{#1,f@#2}&]

(* {{a, f[b]}, {c, f[d]}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option, `/@` is usually my go-to for these sorts of things

```
f := FactorInteger[#][[All,1]]&

{#[[1]], f@#[[2]]} & /@ t1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{2, 5}, {3, 9}, {4, 17}, {5, 33}, {6, 65}, {7, 129}};
```

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[{a_, b_} :> {a, First /@ FactorInteger[b]}] @ list
```

{{2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3,
43}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{2, 5}, {3, 9}, {4, 17}, {5, 33}, {6, 65}, {7, 129}};
```

---

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {{a_, b_}} :> {a, First /@ FactorInteger[b]}]
```

*Result*:

> {{2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3, 43}}}

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, {a_, b_}, ___} :> {a, First /@ FactorInteger[b]}]
```

*Result*:

> {{2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3, 43}}}

Or using `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[{#1, First /@ FactorInteger@#2} &, Thread[list]]
```

*Result*:

> {{2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3, 43}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
t0 = Table[{k, 2^k + 1}, {k, 2, 7}]
```

> {{2, 5}, {3, 9}, {4, 17}, {5, 33}, {6, 65}, {7, 129}}

---

Define:

```
f = If[PrimeQ[#], {#}, Most@Rest@Divisors[#]] &;

t1 = SubsetMap[Map[f], t0, {All, 2}]
```

> {{2, {5}}, {3, {3}}, {4, {17}}, {5, {3, 11}}, {6, {5, 13}}, {7, {3,
> 43}}}

---

It is not the actual question, but the post-processing step can be avoided altogether:

```
t2 = Table[{k, f[2^k + 1]}, {k, 2, 7}]
```

(* same output *)